# mxGraph connection handler mouse cursor does not change to hand cursor

Tags: reactjs, mxgraph

I created a new mxgraph react project. 
When mouse moved to vertex cursor changes to move_cursor. but I want to create a link and cursor will be hand cursor. how can i solve this problem? 
There is a code snippet about connection settings.

```
settingConnection = () => {
    const { graph } = this.state;
    mxConstraintHandler.prototype.intersects = function(
      icon,
      point,
      source,
      existingEdge
    ) {
      return !source || existingEdge || mxUtils.intersects(icon.bounds, point);
    };

    var mxConnectionHandlerUpdateEdgeState =
      mxConnectionHandler.prototype.updateEdgeState;
    mxConnectionHandler.prototype.updateEdgeState = function(pt, constraint) {
      if (pt != null && this.previous != null) {
        var constraints = this.graph.getAllConnectionConstraints(this.previous);
        var nearestConstraint = null;
        var dist = null;

        for (var i = 0; i < constraints.length; i++) {
          var cp = this.graph.getConnectionPoint(this.previous, constraints[i]);

          if (cp != null) {
            var tmp =
              (cp.x - pt.x) * (cp.x - pt.x) + (cp.y - pt.y) * (cp.y - pt.y);

            if (dist == null || tmp < dist) {
              nearestConstraint = constraints[i];
              dist = tmp;
            }
          }
        }

        if (nearestConstraint != null) {
          this.sourceConstraint = nearestConstraint;
        }

        // In case the edge style must be changed during the preview:
        // this.edgeState.style['edgeStyle'] = 'orthogonalEdgeStyle';
        // And to use the new edge style in the new edge inserted into the graph,
        // update the cell style as follows:
        //this.edgeState.cell.style = mxUtils.setStyle(this.edgeState.cell.style, 'edgeStyle', this.edgeState.style['edgeStyle']);
      }

      mxConnectionHandlerUpdateEdgeState.apply(this, arguments);
    };

    if (graph.connectionHandler.connectImage == null) {
      graph.connectionHandler.isConnectableCell = function(cell) {
        return false;
      };
      mxEdgeHandler.prototype.isConnectableCell = function(cell) {
        return graph.connectionHandler.isConnectableCell(cell);
      };
    }

    graph.getAllConnectionConstraints = function(terminal) {
      if (terminal != null && this.model.isVertex(terminal.cell)) {
        return [
          new mxConnectionConstraint(new mxPoint(0.5, 0), true),
          new mxConnectionConstraint(new mxPoint(0, 0.5), true),
          new mxConnectionConstraint(new mxPoint(1, 0.5), true),
          new mxConnectionConstraint(new mxPoint(0.5, 1), true)
        ];
      }
      return null;
    };

    // Connect preview
    graph.connectionHandler.createEdgeState = function(me) {
      var edge = graph.createEdge(
        null,
        null,
        "Edge",
        null,
        null,
        "edgeStyle=orthogonalEdgeStyle"
      );

      return new mxCellState(
        this.graph.view,
        edge,
        this.graph.getCellStyle(edge)
      );
    };
  };
```

Mouse cursor only change to move cursor, but I want to changes to hand cursor when mouse moved to vertex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I deleted some codes,

```
  var mxConnectionHandlerUpdateEdgeState =
      mxConnectionHandler.prototype.updateEdgeState;
    mxConnectionHandler.prototype.updateEdgeState = function(pt, constraint) {
      if (pt != null && this.previous != null) {
        var constraints = this.graph.getAllConnectionConstraints(this.previous);
        var nearestConstraint = null;
        var dist = null;

        for (var i = 0; i < constraints.length; i++) {
          var cp = this.graph.getConnectionPoint(this.previous, constraints[i]);

          if (cp != null) {
            var tmp =
              (cp.x - pt.x) * (cp.x - pt.x) + (cp.y - pt.y) * (cp.y - pt.y);

            if (dist == null || tmp < dist) {
              nearestConstraint = constraints[i];
              dist = tmp;
            }
          }
        }

        if (nearestConstraint != null) {
          this.sourceConstraint = nearestConstraint;
        }

        // In case the edge style must be changed during the preview:
        // this.edgeState.style['edgeStyle'] = 'orthogonalEdgeStyle';
        // And to use the new edge style in the new edge inserted into the graph,
        // update the cell style as follows:
        //this.edgeState.cell.style = mxUtils.setStyle(this.edgeState.cell.style, 'edgeStyle', this.edgeState.style['edgeStyle']);
      }

      mxConnectionHandlerUpdateEdgeState.apply(this, arguments);
    };

    if (graph.connectionHandler.connectImage == null) {
      graph.connectionHandler.isConnectableCell = function(cell) {
        return false;
      };
      mxEdgeHandler.prototype.isConnectableCell = function(cell) {
        return graph.connectionHandler.isConnectableCell(cell);
      };
    }
```

And I wrote this codes,

```
      // Enables connect preview for the default edge style
      graph.connectionHandler.createEdgeState = function(me) {
        var edge = graph.createEdge(null, null, null, null, null);

        return new gr.mxCellState(
          this.graph.view,
          edge,
          this.graph.getCellStyle(edge)
        );
```

I solve this problem :)